# Indexing with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongodb-indexes

I was reading the mongoose docs about indexing and want to find out whether there is a difference between field level indexing and schema level indexing. They mention that "defining indexes at the schema level is necessary when creating compound indexes." Are there any other reasons why I might choose one over the other or it is just a preference?

```js
  const animalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String,
    tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
  });

  animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 }); // schema level
```

Answer (score 0):

When developing your indexing strategy you should have a deep understanding of your application’s queries. Before you build indexes, map out the types of `queries` you will run so that you can build indexes that reference those fields.
for example you have a query just find based on one field like `name` so you can indexing `name` in `field level` but if you have a query that find based on `name` and `tag` so you should indexing `name` and `tag` together for this situation you should use indexing in `schema level`